# Tricky Partial Fraction Decomposition

Tags: laplace-transform, partial-fractions

Let $\omega_0 \ne \omega$, solve $y'' + \omega_0^2 y = \sin(\omega t)$ by Laplace transform using the initial conditions $y(0)=0$, and $y'(0)=0$.

I have gotten down as far as the partial fraction decomposition being this, $\frac{\omega}{(s^2 + \omega_0^2)(s^2+\omega^2)}$ but am confused as how to proceed from there.

Comment: Posting this to see if there's a better or easier solution for this particular partial fraction decomposition.  My method works, but it seems very complicated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From
$$A(s^2 + \omega^2) + B(s^2 + \omega_0^2)
=(A+B)s^2 + (A\omega^2 + B\omega_0^2) = 1,$$
you get
$$A+B=0
,\qquad
A \omega^2 + B \omega_0^2=1
,
$$
where you can solve for $A$ and $B$. Only $s$ is considered as a variable here; $\omega$ and $\omega_0$ are constants.

Answer (score 1):

We have $\frac{\omega}{(s^2 + \omega_0^2)(s^2 + \omega^2)}$ and we want to find
$\frac{A}{(s^2 + \omega_0^2)} + \frac{B}{(s^2 + \omega^2)}$, ignoring the factor
of $\omega$ that we can multiply
through later, we have that we want to find $A$ and $B$ such that $A(s^2 + \omega^2) +
B(s^2 + \omega_0^2) = 1$.  Therefore, $As^2 + Bs^2 = 0s^2$ and $A\omega^2 = 0$ and
$B\omega_0^2 = 0$ and we have a mysterious 1 left over.  That means the
expressions $A$ and $B$ must be more complex than simple natural numbers or
expressions in $\omega$, $s$ and $\omega_0$.  (In fact, Mathematica flatly refuses to use partial fractions at all on this particular expression.)

Instead you need to be a bit tricky to get the partial fraction for this
expression.  Consider what would happen if you multiplied through by $\frac{\omega^2 -
\omega_0^2}{\omega^2 - \omega_0^2}$ and held the denominator away as a factor for later.*

Now we have $A(s^2 + \omega^2) + B(s^2 + \omega_0^2) = (\omega^2 - \omega_0^2)$, which gives:

$$\begin{split}
As^2 + Bs^2 &= 0s^2  \\
A\omega^2 &= \omega^2  \\
B\omega_0^2 &= -\omega_0^2 \\
\end{split}$$

so $A = 1$ and $B = -1$.  So our partial fractions are:

$$\frac{\frac1{\omega^2 - \omega_0^2}}{s^2 + \omega_0^2} - \frac{\frac1{\omega^2 -
\omega_0^2}}{s^2 + \omega^2} = \frac1{(s^2 + \omega_0^2)(s^2 + \omega^2)}$$

And let's not forget our factor of $\omega$ that we left behind initially:

$$\frac{\omega}{(\omega^2 - \omega_0^2)(s^2 + \omega_0^2)} -
\frac{\omega}{(\omega^2 - \omega_0^2)(s^2 + \omega^2)} = \frac{\omega}{(s^2 + \omega_0^2)(s^2 + \omega^2)}$$

The inverse Laplace transform of the second term is easy, you get simply
$\frac{\sin(\omega t)}{\omega^2 - \omega_0^2}$.

But the first term is a bit trickier, where can I get a $\omega_0$?  Well, let's
just make one by multiplying by $\frac{\omega_0}{\omega_0}$!

$$\frac{\omega}{(\omega^2 - \omega_0^2)(s^2 + \omega_0^2)} = \frac{\omega
\omega_0}{\omega_0(\omega^2 - \omega_0^2)(s^2 + \omega_0^2)}$$

And now we can take the inverse transform:

$$\frac{\omega \sin(\omega_0 t)}{\omega_0(\omega^2 - \omega_0^2)}$$

And finally we can combine everything by multiplying the first term through by
$\frac{\omega_0}{\omega_0}$ as well:

$$\frac{\omega \sin(\omega_0 t) - \omega_0 \sin(\omega t)}{\omega_0 (\omega^2 - \omega_0^2)}$$

And check to ensure that our result satisfies our original differential equation:

$$ \begin{split}
y &= \frac{\omega \sin(\omega_0 t) - \omega_0 \sin(\omega t)}{\omega_0 (\omega^2 - \omega_0^2)} \\
y' &= \frac{\omega (\cos(\omega_0 t) - \cos(\omega t))}{\omega^2 - \omega_0^2} \\
y'' &= \frac{\omega (\omega \sin(\omega t) - \omega_0 \sin(\omega_0 t))}{\omega^2 - \omega_0^2}
\end{split}$$

So:

$$\begin{split}
y'' + \omega_0^2 y &= \frac{\omega (\omega \sin(\omega t) - \omega_0 \sin(\omega_0 t))}{\omega^2 - \omega_0^2} + \omega_0^2 \frac{\omega \sin(\omega_0 t) - \omega_0 \sin(\omega t)}{\omega_0 (\omega^2 - \omega_0^2)} \\
&= \frac{\omega (\omega \sin(\omega t) - \omega_0 \sin(\omega_0 t)) + \omega_0 (\omega \sin(\omega_0 t) - \omega_0 \sin(\omega t))}{\omega^2 - \omega_0^2} \\
&= \frac{\omega^2 \sin(\omega t) - \omega \omega_0 \sin(\omega_0 t)) + \omega \omega_0 \sin(\omega_0 t) - \omega_0^2 \sin(\omega t)}{\omega^2 - \omega_0^2}  \\
&= \frac{(\omega^2 - \omega_0^2) \sin(\omega t)}{\omega^2 - \omega_0^2} \\
y'' + \omega_0^2 y &= \sin(\omega t) \\
\end{split}$$

Which was our original equation.

* A point on how I arrived at this seemingly arbitrary factor.  I noted before
that I had a mystery 1, and how everything was coming up zeros.  So I needed to
"create" something solvable.  Which meant I needed to come up with some way
having some of the variables in my expression.  This was an easy way of
producing a $\omega^2$ and a $\omega_0^2$ while still having $A+B = 0$ as
required by the $s^2$ equation.  The fact that the problem also specifies $\omega - \omega_0 \ne 0$ can clue you in to the fact that the solution almost certainly involves dividing by $\omega - \omega_0$ at some point.

Comment: The conclusion “$A \omega^2=B \omega_0^2=0$ and a mysterious $1$ is left over” is wrong, since $\omega$ and $\omega_0$ are just constants, not independent variables. The correct conclusion is $A \omega^2+B \omega_0^2=1$, and this together with $A+B=0$ immediately gives you $A$ and $B$.

Comment: If you enter this as an answer I will mark it as accepted.  This was the simple step I was missing.

Comment: OK, as you wish. :-)